# Cross-compile C++ project for ARM64 with bazel

Tags: linux, cross-compiling, bazel

I'm trying to cross-compile hello-world C++ project with bezel for ARM64 device. I work with Linux/Ubuntu x86_64 as a built-host-PC. I'm following the [Building a C++ Project](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/3.2.0/tutorial/cpp.html).

I can build the project for host-PC.

```
bazel build //main:hello-world
```

Now I'm trying to cross-compile this project for ARM64 device as

```
bazel build --cpu=aarch64 //main:hello-world
```

I used different configuration for `--cpu=arm64, --cpu=aarch64, --cpu=arm64-v8a` and it does not wrok.

I'd model the environment as a `platform` to automatically select the appropriate toolchain installed via `"crossbuild-essential-arm64"` package for build action.

The cross-compilation build is done on PC-host - *host platform* - and executed there - *execution platform* - so the platforms are the same, but the - *target platform* - is different where the hello-world C++ project will run.

How to cross-compile the C++ project for arm64 target with bazel using `--platforms` properly?

Comment: I've been looking for the same, except I'm trying to cross-compile an existing project. I've found that [Tensorflow](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/third_party/toolchains/cpus/arm) has some bits that are meant to work, but I have no idea how to paste these into another project and it doesn't help that there is so much config, I rather unimpressed...

Comment: I found https://github.com/mjbots/rpi_bazel for cross-compiling C++ to a Raspberry Pi using clang - looks quite complicated ... :(

Comment: https://github.com/gregestren/snippets/tree/master/custom_cc_toolchain_with_platforms

Comment: Have you seen https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/tutorial/cc-toolchain-config.html? I have managed to work from there, but faced other issues with one of the dependencies, will report back on success. I think it should be easier in a greenfield project.

Comment: As you pointed that info it uses `--crosstool_top` and other [Building with platforms C++](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/platforms-intro.html#c) says it's the legacy approach.I guess both should solve the same one.